# Spring + Tiles - 404 error when accessing jsp folder

Tags: spring, jsp, http-status-code-404, tiles

Basically, what happens when I launch my project is that the views are all resolved properly and the correct jsp is being looked for, however there seems to be something blocking tiles access to my jsp folder inside the WEB-INF folder.

The exact problem is that when I go to localhost/FitterBlog/index.htm I get a 404 error:

```
The requested resource (/FitterBlog/jsp/layout/layout.jsp) is not available.
```

I have the following code:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.fitterblog.controllers"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- tiles configuration -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="FitterBlog" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/layout/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="nav" value="/jsp/layout/nav.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/layout/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/index.jsp" />
</definition>   
</tiles-definitions>
```

MainController.java:

```
package com.fitterblog.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value="index.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index() {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
}
}
```

I have triple checked that all the JSP files are located in the correct location, as in the layout.jsp file that gets the 404 error is located in WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp.

Comment: shouldn't you put <definition name="baseLayout" template="WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp"> there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my application the jsp's are located in subdirectories of `WEB-INF`.

If it is the same for you you need to change the tiles config a bit

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="FitterBlog" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="nav" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/nav.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="index" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
</definition>   
</tiles-definitions>
```

Comment: Perfect! I coulda sworn I tried that, maybe I missed the front slash or something. Oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to store your JSPs in WEB-INF then just set the prefix property in the ViewResolver

```
<beanid="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: He is using tiles -- then there is no JstlView, instead a org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView is unsed. -- And i doubt that the TilesView use the prefix and suffix in the way you expect them

Comment: yeah, my first comment was also that but are you sure

Comment: I have only strong doubt. But I am not 100% sure. The reason why I have doubt is, that prefix and suffix are features of UrlBasedViewResolver. But I think tiles will not use the UrlBasedViewResolver to load the parts (tiles). I would expect, that if you set pre and postfix like suggestes, it would result only in the fact, that you need to add "/WEB-INF" to the NAMES of all tile definitions.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too. Prefix and suffix didn't work. Too bad, would be nice for sure!